# Python Social Auth - - Django - find url names

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

So, when using python social auth with django, one has to point the login social button to different urls, depending on the social network. This is an example:

```
<form action="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-facebook">&nbsp</span>Login with Facebook </button>
</form>

<form action="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-google">&nbsp</span>Login with Google</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, the url arguments are not intuitive, sometimes they are the name of the social network, like `facebook`, sometimes it is something more complex like `google-oauth2`. Is there a way I can figure out what argument to pass into de function? Now, I need login buttons for instagram and twitter. I can't find a clear reference in the docs about this.

Best,

Alejandro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation lacks a reference to this. If anyone needs to find the name of the app to use in the `{% url %}` declaration, it can be found in the source code under `social.apps.backends`- each backend is a python file that declares a class, each class declares an attribute called `name`. In the case of Instagram, it looks like this:

```
class InstagramOAuth2(BaseOAuth2):
    name = 'instagram'
    ....
```

So, that means the social login button should look something like this:

```
{% url 'social:begin' 'instagram' %}
```